# $window error '$window not defined' with google analytics code in Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-analytics

How could I define / inject to allow use & clear up my error of `$window` not defined in my `js/app.js` file, when trying to run GA (google analytics code) in my Angular app.

**Error:** '**$window not defined'**

```
   .run(function($rootScope, APIServer, social, $location, music, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {

        // $window.ga('create', 'UA-55555555-5', 'auto'); <-- here

        /*
         * Scroll down to comments if available
         */
        $anchorScroll.yOffset = 70;
        //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
            // $window.ga('send', 'pageview', $location.path()); <-- here
            $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
            $anchorScroll();  
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject $window too.

```
.run(function($rootScope, APIServer, social, $location, music, $anchorScroll, $routeParams, $window) {

        // $window.ga('create', 'UA-55555555-5', 'auto'); <-- here

        /*
         * Scroll down to comments if available
         */
        $anchorScroll.yOffset = 70;
        //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
            // $window.ga('send', 'pageview', $location.path()); <-- here
            $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
            $anchorScroll();  
        });
```